# macos theme import with ohmyzzh in command line

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, macos-catalina, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to import the powerlevel10k theme into my macOS terminal.

Here is my .zhrc:

```
test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh"

source ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh

ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

[ -f ~/.fzf.zsh ] && source ~/.fzf.zsh
```

This is the error I get in my terminal:

```
/Users/rocky/.zshrc:6: permission denied: /Users/rocky/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme
```

**UPDATE**

```
test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh"


source ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh

ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

[ -f ~/.fzf.zsh ] && source ~/.fzf.zsh
```

Comment: You forgot the newline before `source`. You aren't executing the `source` command; you are trying to execute the theme file with `ZSH_THEME` set to a string ending in `source` in its environment.

Comment: @chepner check out my update. does that seem good now?

Comment: No, the line where you set `ZSH_THEME`; you need a semicolon or a newline before `source`.

Comment: `ZSH_THEME="..."; source ~/powerlevel/...`.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to reveal this error. The only one your need to do it's take a new line.

```
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"    # don't junction,not work
source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme
```

Comment: You aren't supposed to execute that file; it needs to be sourced.